# Activating a function by clicking outside the box

Tags: javascript, html

Alright so I'm having a bit of trouble with getting a function to work. All I have to do is to make the function activate once i click out from a HTML box.

```
<hmtl>
<body>
<center>
<script>
function calculateTax() {
var a = document.getElementById('boxone').value;
var b = document.getElementById('boxtwo').value;
var c = a/100*18;

b = c + a;

document.getElementById('boxone').value = a;
document.getElementById('boxtwo').value = b;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="boxone" value="">
<input type="text" id="boxtwo" value=""><br>
<input type="hidden" onclick="calculateTax()">
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I should put instead of onclick and why my formula does not work.Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add, special thanks to Barmar for helping me get this far

Comment: What is wrong with your formula?

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Dmc9Z/1/

Basically, you can add an `onclick` event to the `body`. I also added a button there which can submit it too, depending on what you want.

The reason your code wasn't working was because the input was being processed as a string. When you were 'adding', you were just concatenating values to the string. I added `parseInt` to fix that for you. I also removed some redundant code.

Comment: You might consider @Simon Brahan 's answer.  The OnBlur event of the textbox will fire regardless of where you click.  If you use the body's onclick event, it will not fire unless you click another control.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `onBlur` event listener.

`<input type="text" id="boxone" value="" onBlur="calculateTax()">`

onBlur is the event called when an element loses focus - when you click away from an input, for example.

Adding an onClick to the body will work, but isn't the best approach because it will make the function run every time anyone clicks anywhere on your page - not just when they click away from the input.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep your javascript and html separated. You can add an event listener to the body and make you it only fires when it's not an input field, for example like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("click", function(target) {
    if (target.nodeName === "INPUT") return false; // if our focus is an input field we don't want to fire the event
    calculateTax();
}, false);
```